# Probability poker game task

Tags: probability-or-statistics, discrete

I have this task:

[image]

And I've got this far in my mathematica program, however I can't figure out why my probability turns out 0?

```
ClearAll["'*"]

(* Deck *)

(* We let colors (black, red, green and blue) be represented by the 
first position in a 3-digit integer and the values 
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) be represented by the third position in the 
3-digit integer *)

deck = Sort[Join[Range[101, 110], Range[201, 209], Range[301, 308], 
   Range[401, 407]]]


Out[174]= {101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 201, \
202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, \
307, 308, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407}

hands = Subsets[deck, {5}];
Short[hands]

Out[176]/Short= {{101, 102, 103, 104, 105},
 {101, 102, 103, 104, 106}, <<278253>>, {403, 404, 405, 406, 407}}


pairQ[{___, x_, x_, ___}] := True; (* a pair *)
pairQ[{___, x_, x_, ___, y_, y_, ___} /; 
   x != y] := False; (* two pairs *)
pairQ[{___, x_, x_, x_, ___}] := False; (* three of a kind *)
pairQ[{___, x_, x_, x_, x_, ___}] := False; (* four of a kind *)
pairQ[{___}] := False (* else *)


Count[hands, _?(pairQ)]/Length[hands]

Out[199]= 0
```

Any suggestions would kind!

Comment: Please paste your code into the question, not a screenshot. There are obviously no pairs at all because all cards are unique. You need to take your cards modulo 100 so they pair up in the number but not the suit.

Comment: @flinty Sorry about that, I don't know how to paste the code? Could I ask you what you mean by that ? (I'm not that great with Mathematica, and I'm learning)

Comment: Select the code in mathematica, copy, and paste. You can edit your question by clicking on _edit_ near the bottom. When you paste the code, you should use three backticks ( ` ) to mark a block of code.

Comment: To expand on my earlier comment: You've got `pairQ[{___, x_, x_, ___}]` which means it's looking to match a pair of x's somewhere in the middle of your code. None of your hands have pairs because you've created a unique number for every card by combining the suit and rank into an integer. You need to extract ranks of the cards first, then test for a pair. To do this you'd do `Mod[hand,100]` first to get a rank list. Likewise to get a list of suits you'd do `Quotient[hand,100]`. This is more trouble than it's worth - so instead you should just use a list of `{rank,suite}` pairs like my answer.

Comment: This appears to be homework (or a test). If so, please tag it as such.

In addition, to allow users to write responsive answers, clarify what the desired "...census method described in the preparation section." is. Readers should not have to infer/search for such things.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use patterns here. They just make more trouble figuring them out and debugging. There's also no reason to introduce a coding scheme for the cards at this stage, which is a bit of a premature optimization.

```
ranks[hand_] := Sort[hand[[All, 1]]]
suits[hand_] := Sort[hand[[All, 2]]]
countranks[hand_] := Values@Counts@ranks@hand
pairQ[hand_] := Not[DuplicateFreeQ[ranks[hand]]]
twoPairsQ[hand_] := Count[countranks@hand, 2] == 2
threeOfAKindQ[hand_] := MemberQ[countranks@hand, 3]
fourOfAKindQ[hand_] := MemberQ[countranks@hand, 4]
fullHandQ[hand_] := ContainsExactly[countranks@hand,{3,2}]
straightQ[hand_] := ContainsOnly[Differences[Sort[ranks[hand]]], {1}]
flushQ[hand_] := SameQ @@ suits[hand]
straightFlushQ[hand_] := flushQ[hand] && straightQ[hand]

(* in order of best to worst *)
scoringFunctions = {
  {straightFlushQ, "Straight Flush"},
  {flushQ, "Flush"},
  {straightQ, "Straight"},
  {fullHandQ, "Full Hand"},
  {fourOfAKindQ, "Four of a kind"},
  {threeOfAKindQ, "Three of a kind"},
  {twoPairsQ, "Two pairs"},
  {pairQ, "Pair"}
};

bestScore[hand_] := Last[SelectFirst[scoringFunctions,First[#][hand]&]]

deck = Join[
   {#, Black} & /@ Range[10],
   {#, Red} & /@ Range[9],
   {#, Green} & /@ Range[8],
   {#, Blue} & /@ Range[7]
];

hands = Subsets[deck, {5}];
CountsBy[hands, pairQ][True]/Length[hands]

(* result: 11021/17391 *)

(* best hand probabilities *)
#/Length[hands]& /@ KeyDrop[CountsBy[hands, bestScore], "NotFound"]
(** 
<|"Straight Flush" -> 3/46376,
 "Flush" -> 437/278256, 
 "Pair" -> 17395/34782,
 "Straight" -> 717/46376, 
 "Two pairs" -> 737/8432,
 "Three of a kind" -> 5741/139128, 
 "Full Hand" -> 1163/278256,
 "Four of a kind" -> 35/46376|>
**)
```

Comment: This code generates incorrect results.

Comment: @ciao could you explain, I may have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Note that in this code I consider it correct that {1,1,1,2,3} is both a pair and a three-of-a-kind which is why I wrote `bestScore`. If Vetenskap wants to count exclusively then that should be made more clear.